# Consulta em colunas diferentes ao mesmo tempo no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, query

Eu tenho duas tabelas, a primeira não importa por enquanto, a segunda segue exemplo abaixo e iremos nomear de tabela2:

| id | coluna1 | coluna2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | valor1 | valor2 |
| 2 | valor2 | valor1 |
| 3 | valor3 | valor4 |
| 4 | valor5 | valor6 |

E tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela1
WHERE coluna1 IN (SELECT coluna1 FROM tabela2)
```

A questão é: eu gostaria que ele fizesse esse *select* entre parênteses apenas quando existir os mesmos valores, mas em colunas diferentes que no caso seriam apenas as linhas 1 e 2 do meu exemplo, os mesmos valores existem na linha de baixo, porém em colunas diferentes. Seria possível?
Na consulta eu gostaria que ele retornasse o resultado abaixo:

| **id** | **coluna1** | **coluna2** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | valor1 | valor2 |
| 2 | valor2 | valor1 |

Comment: Henry, vc tentou escrever tudo tão genérico que chega a ficar confuso. Quer um resultado onde o valor da coluna1 exista na coluna2 em outra linha é isso?

Comment: Desculpa se não consegui me expressar muito bem, estou iniciando agora. Seria isso, porém, para entrar nessa condição o valor da coluna 2 também precisa existir na coluna 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está um pouco confuso mas pelo que entendi poderia dizer que

> retorne os registros onde o valor de "coluna1" exista também em
> "coluna2" e vice-versa

Para isso precisa usar o `EXISTS`, que vai verificar se existe um registro com deterninada condição numa *subquery*.

Dai, precisa fazer a *subquery* validar coluna1 e coluna2, assim por exemplo:

```
select coluna1 from tabela2
where  exists (select coluna2 
                 from tabela2 t2
                where t2.coluna2 = tabela2.coluna1)
    or exists (select coluna1 
                 from tabela2 t2
                where t2.coluna1 = tabela2.coluna2)
```

Essa ai seria a subquery dentro do `IN`.
Pode ver funcionando aqui (no exemplo usei só numeros para simplificar) : [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df52b2d/2)

Comment: Cara, acho que deu certo, mas se caso não retornasse nenhum resultado nessa subquery eu precisaria retornar um valor padrão, é possível?

Comment: sim é, pode usar a função `IFNULL` , assim: `SELECT IFNULL( ( .. aqui vai toda a sua query ), 'nao encontrado')`, onde "não encontrado" é o valor padrão que quer retornar, que pode ser qualquer coisa. Não esqueça de aceitar ou votar na resposta se foi util ou resolveu a dúvida :)

Comment: Não consegui utilizar o ifnull, mas consegui fazer uma outra condição. De qualquer forma sua resposta me salvou, muito obrigado!